# Original Method Called even after using Mockito.Spy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spy

I tried all the advice given on many websites but nothing seems to be working in my case.

Test class

```
@Autowired
Service service;

@Test
public void Test() throws Exception {
    Service service1 = Mockito.spy(service);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    Mockito.doReturn(obj).when(service1).getFunc(any(JSONObject.class));
    String str = service1.sendFunc(any(JSONObject.class));
    assertNotEquals(null, str);
}
```

Sevice Class

```
public class Service {
    public String sendFunc(JSONObject arg) {
        String str = getFunc(arg);
    }
    public String getFunc(JSONObject arg) {
        return "Pass";
    }
}
```

After debugging I realised that even after mocking it. The original method `getFunc()` is being called and nothing seems to be the problem. Please help figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved. Apparently, I was sending `any(JSONObject.class)` while using `service1.sendFunc(any(JSONObject.class))` but when I sent `new JSONObject()` it worked properly.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

1. This line is wrong:

```java
String str = service1.sendFunc(any(JSONObject.class));
```

`any()` is only used for mocking, not for the real call.

2. `any(JSONOject.class)`

> Matches any object of given type, excluding nulls.

But you don't pass an object, you pass a class, which is not an object of that class. So I'd suppose you to replace it with `eq()`. (I think you don't need an `ArgumentMatcher` in that case at all)

Comment: Changed but still, it is doing the same thing. Don't know why the original method is called

Answer (score 0):

If you are writting `@SpringBootTest` (so if you are loading app context), then you should use `@SpyBean` annotation like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SimpleTest {

    @SpyBean
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(myService.getFunc(any())).thenReturn(something);
        
        String str = myService.sendFunc(...);

        assertNotEquals(null, str);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to load context and test class in isolation, you can use `@Spy` annotation or `Mockito.spy()`:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @Spy
    MyService service1;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

       // MyService service1 = Mockito.spy(new MyService()); // if without @Spy

        when(service1.getFunc(any())).thenReturn(something);

        String str = service1.sendFunc(obj);
        assertNotEquals(null, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code because even after trying both these methods the programme is still calling the original method.